# git cherry-pick says local changes exist, but git status says nothing

Tags: git, cherry-pick

```
$ git cherry-pick 5de83068
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        Components/ApplicationEnums/Application.cs
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

**UPDATE** Sorry, I switched to another branch, and switched back again, and can't reproduce this anymore :(

Comment: Sounds like you managed to get your index out of sync somehow.

Comment: @Jefromi, so switching branches mended that. What is the 'official' way of re-syncing the index? And do you have any idea how I could have got into that state? (if you care to answer that, I'll update my question accordingly)

Comment: I'm really not sure how it'd have happened. A `reset --soft` might verify things, and a `reset` (`--mixed`, the default) would update the index from the current commit.

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue. 
***Error was - error: Your local changes would be overwritten by cherry-pick.
hint: Commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
fatal: cherry-pick failed***
The reason  for me was  I had a file in staging area that I don't wants to commit. I moved that file from staging area and tried to chery-pick again and that was a success.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure whats the problem but you can reset your working copy with the follwing statement:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I have an origin/master, this is a standalone repository.

Comment: OK, so can you provide us your .git/config?

Comment: There's no reason to reset to origin's master. You really don't want to move the branch - it's already where you want it, there's just something funky in index/work tree. Resetting to HEAD (`git reset`, or *maybe* `git reset --hard`) is plenty.

Comment: This is a slightly dangerous suggestion, not everyone is working on master or wants to reset to it.

Comment: 12+ years later and this was the solution I needed. Thanks. (I reset to a different branch than master though.)

Answer (score 2):

The patch from the cherry-pick does not align in terms of the seams of where the changes would be applied. Do a --no-commit to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem when using git on a virtual machine, where the working copy was a VMware shared folder.  I don't really know what the solution is.  In my case I was able to get git to move away the changes it thought existed via `git stash` (upon inspection appeared to be completely empty); after the changes had been moved away I could cherry-pick on top of the now clean working copy.  (After this, I just deleted the stash.)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the error while running

```
git cherry-pick -x <commit1> <commit2> <commit3>
```

Running the cherry-picks independently works:

```
echo <commit1> <commit2> <commit3> | xargs -n 1 git cherry-pick -x
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here from googling about that weird message and I'd like to put my two cents.

For what is worth, my scenario is as following:

- real code resides in a Virtual Machine
- Mac OS connects to it via samba network sharing
- Visual Studio Code is running on my Mac
- git is running from within VS Code

I did experienced what OP wrote and **I resolved by doing... nothing but wait!** :)

Maybe there was a cache or a network problem, who knows.