# Why are local changes not showing in git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

Yesterday I started having the strangest issue with my local git repository. If I make any local changes, they don't show up in "git status". I usually use visual studio (VS 2017 Professional) to look at changes and do comparisons, and any changes I make do not appear here either.

When I attempted a git pull, I got the error message that *"Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:".. "Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge".*

I have tried doing a reset to head / stash "changes" / deleting the branch and pulling it down again. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264104/git-cherry-pick-says-local-changes-exist-but-git-status-says-nothing) looks very similar to my issue but none of the solutions offered worked for me.
When I tried **git reset --hard origin/master** I got the error:

```
error: Entry '.gitignore' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
```

I tried following suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248029/git-pull-error-entry-foo-not-uptodate-cannot-merge) and again, no luck.

EDIT:
The main issue here right now is that any changes I make are now showing up. I have been able to pull latest changes by renaming the file git thought had been edited and later removing it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248029/git-pull-error-entry-foo-not-uptodate-cannot-merge/1995378#1995378)), but my local changes are still ignored.
I looked at my .gitignore and cannot find anything that would indicate all files in my project should be ignored..

I removed everything from my .gitignore file and when I did this all the files I want to ignore appear - i.e. dlls etc. showed up as changed but all the files I want to include - i.e. all code files still do not appear in my list!!
I have also tried [undoing all files that skip-worktree was applied to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131197/undo-git-update-index-skip-worktree) in case this had somehow happened.

I have no idea what's happened here.
I have never had an issue like this before and have searched online for a similar issue and cannot find a solution.

Any suggestions on what else to try would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995378/1671066?

Comment: Thanks @MichaWiedenmann. I tried renaming the "changed" file and it let me do a git pull so I now have the latest. But I still have an issue with changes: Any changes I make do not show up in git status...? By the way this is the case with ALL files - not just one or two